# IBM WorkLight application is not lightweight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing a hybrid app using worklight, and so far I just have couple of screens in my app. But when I run this app in my Android phone, if I check the apk file it's size is showing as 4.4 MB! I'm not even 20% through my app development and still it is so heavy.
Is this an issue with worklight or there is a way in worklight to keep your app lightweight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up. We are aware of this and are making way on reducing our application file size in a future release.

I'm not in front of my work machine at the moment, so I can't test tips before giving you them, buuuttt... in your native\assets folder there should be a icudt46l.zip file.
If you do not intend on using the JSONStore feature, try deleting this file and re-building your app. This should reduce the filesize considerably, but again I can't guarantee what happens during runtime (nothing bad should happen...).

Comment: yes, i tried that and it works! about 50% reduction in size :) i'll look forward to the next release

Comment: @IdanAdar Size is still big for 1 page application in 6.1 worklight release. How to reduce it.

Comment: If you will bother to add some more details to your question I can try to answer it... what is the current size? which environment? what are you using in your app? any cordova plug-ins? jsonstore? what is it? Open a new question. Don't use comments to ask questions.